# $cordovaLocalNotification - TypeError - cannot read property 'local' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, localnotification

I am running into an issue while utilizing $cordovaLocalNotification within my ionic app where the below code yields an error message **TypeError: Cannot read property 'local' of undefined**

```
try{
  if($scope.active.checked){
    $cordovaLocalNotification.schedule({
      id: 1,
      title: 'Notification',
      text: 'You are currently publishing your location.'
    }).then(function(result){
      AlertService.notify('Success', 'Successfully notified customer')
    }, function(err){
      AlertService.notify('Error', 'Failed to notify customer')
    });
  } else {
    $cordovaLocalNotification.cancel(1);
  }
}catch(err){
  AlertService.notify('Issue', err)
}
```

So, after reading a few responses around needing to verify ionicPlatform.ready() and ensuring the plugin is installed properly (and verifying those aren't the issues), I am at a lost. I believe this issue is caused by **cordova.plugins.notification** not being defined, but I'm not sure why this plugin isn't being loaded properly.

From Ionic, I have the following plugins:

```
cordova-plugin-app-event 1.2.0 "Application Events"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.3.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.4 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.3 "Device"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.0 "Whitelist"
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification 0.8.4 "LocalNotification"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

So far, for my own sanity, I have:

1. Installed the plugin manually using **cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification**
2. Removed platform, remove plugins, then execute **ionic state restore**

Also, a good item to note is I am utilizing ionicView to test. All/any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you testing this? Browser or a device? I believe notifications are a native thing, therefore they will not work on a browser

Comment: I am using ionicView, which is Native.

Comment: which wont work in a browser so it might go undefined. Check if it works on phone

Comment: Its not in a browser...IonicView is a mobile app that will utilize ionic's framework to display an app in native OS. It works with the 'camera' plugin, so I know its native OS.

Comment: so wait you're gettin that error when debugging on a phone?

Comment: Yes, I use that AlertService.notify to essentially make a popup that publishes the error in try-catch.

Comment: ah well, then its not what I was thinking, hopefully someone gets the solution. I'll upvote the question might help and i might end up sometimes with this :)

Comment: Appreciate it @Marko ! Ive been burned by browser v native when debugging ionic many times, so it was a good callout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that mocking this on the emulator or physical device works fine. So it was a good learning experience that not all cordova plugins operate in ionicView